# Magento SKUs not working in basic search

Tags: magento

Search has stopped working for complete and partial SKUs on a site I am in the process of developing, this functionality has previously worked.

Diffing an older .SQL for the site when this worked I can't see any changes to core_config_data that would effect the site in this way.

Search is set to combined and like. SKUs are still searchable from the advanced search page.

Does anyone have any idea what tables that I should should be looking at for changes effecting search behavior? My hunch is that there is some backend change causing this.

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone have any idea what tables that I should should be looking at for changes effecting search behaviour?

Yep, it's `catalogsearch_fulltext`. Magento fills this table during partial and full reindex of "Catalog Search" index.

BTW, I think the problem is in the attribute's settings. Go to Admin Panel -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage attributes -> (chose SKU attribute) -> Use in Quick Search -> Value should be "Yes"

Comment: Thank you for the advice vsushkov. Quick search attribute is set to yes. Looking through the catalogsearch_fulltext table now.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all files under var/locks and then reindex.

Answer (score 1):

Also be sure to check under "Product Information"->General->Visibility that it is set to "Catalog, Search" instead of just "Catalog". If you change settings, you may have to rebuild indexes and refresh cache.